# Android TensorFlow returns error "Object Tracking Support Not found"

Tags: android, tensorflow

I am trying to make TensorFlow work in my Android device.

I had followed [this guide from TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/mobile/android_build) on how to download and run the sample apps. TF Classify works well, but as I tried TF Detect, I hit an error. I then solved this by forcing `CameraActivity.useCamera2API = true` as per [this GitHub Thread.](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/12431)

After running again, TF Detect and the other samples are now working too.

However when I open the TF Detect, a small toast appears:

```
Object tracking support not found. see tensorflow/examples/android/README.md
```

What happens when I use the TF Detect App is that it can detect the objects, but as soon as it shifts to a new one, the previous detection it made would be lost, even if there was minimal to no movement at all. The tracking feature would be greatly helpful with the workflow we plan to build on top of this existing example.

I have checked the readme at the android examples from Tensorflow, but I don't think I've found anything that could help with my issue.

Answer (score 0):

if you look at the readme.md file it says that you need to use cmake as the build system not java, to make the acquisition process fast enough to permit object tracking.

Mike